# Вопрос по картинке, как правильно сверстать и вырезать

Tags: html, css

[image: http://prntscr.com/bbah3c]
Вопросы на картинке?

1. Как вырезать волнистую линию
2. Размещение дива "Личного кабинета" в верхнем черном блоке-диве, и див "Хидер" с рыбой сверху оступается, использовала отрицательные margin для дива "Хидер" , не помогло...
3. Привожу код

```css
.top_top_menu_wrap{ 
 /*width: 960px;*/
 width: 1020px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.my_room{
 width:155px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:#00963d;
 float:right;
}
.header{
 height:185px;/*160px*/
 background:url('../img/fish_header.jpg') no-repeat  100% 0% ;
 width:1020px;
 z-index: 5;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_top_menu_wrap">
  <div class="my_room">
    <img src="/bitrix/templates/main2/img/person.png" alt="person">
    <span>
     <a class="email" href="/personal/">Личный кабинет</a>
    </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="header">
</div>
```

Comment: в стародавние времена мой дед делал через png  вырезаешь кусочек с треугольничками кидаешь блок и ему бэкграунд, репит сделает свое дело, ну а сейчас валом способов

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать CSS свойство clip-path. Поддерживается не всеми браузерами, почитайте о поддержке [здесь](http://caniuse.com). Также можно наложить повторяющуюся картинку, но clip-path предпочтительнее. Можно сделать баннер сразу с треугольничками сверху. Можно сделать при помощи SVG. Как говорится, на вкус и цвет. Но все-таки предпочтительнее, опять же, clip-path, который специально для этого и создавался.
2. Использовать отрицательные margin'ы - вообще плохая практика. Суть вопроса не совсем понятна. Какие черные блоки? Какой div "хидер"? Вы либо выложите код, либо точнее объясните, что именно требуется, пожалуйста.

Насколько я понял, у вас не получается разместить корзину и баланс сверху справа от рыбы. Вы можете просто не объединять личный кабинет с хедером, тогда он "выйдет" за его пределы. Конечно, не все так просто, еще надо будет много с чем поиграться. Но у меня даже кода нет, чтобы вам помочь. Поэтому, подробности в студию.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код и я поправлю свой ответ.

Comment: Да ладно, использование отрицательных margin это не плохая практика, если использовать там, где это действительно необходимо :)

Comment: @MasterAlex Здесь это точно не необходимо. Нет смысла располагать блок внутри другого блока, чтобы потом "отразить" его при помощи -margin'ов.

Comment: Ну да, без кода не понять, что хочет сделать автор, но в данном случае отрицательные  margin точно не нужны.

Comment: "Можно сделать баннер сразу с треугольничками сверху. Можно сделать при помощи SVG"- Это как? Код позже скину, если не разюерусь-нет под рукой...

Comment: @NNN Как сделать сразу баннер с треугольничками. Когда в фотошопе, пэйнте (да где угодно) вы делаете сам баннер, то прямо там вы можете сделать его верхнюю границу состоящую из треугольников. Решение имеет свои плюсы и минусы. Плюсы: не надо париться с кроссбраузерностью, все 200% будет так, как надо; не надо писать вообще никакого кода. Минусы: если сменить BG Color, то придется перерисовывать все баннеры; это может не устроить вашего дизайнера (хотя это его проблемы); каждый баннер придеся переделывать.

Comment: @NNN При помощи SVG. Рисуем треугольники, вставляем "сверху" на баннер. Плюсы: не зависит от ширины баннера, везде будет одинаковая ширина треугольников. Минусы: плюсы могу стать минусами в определенных условиях.

Comment: @NNN можно нарисовать (__не__ SVG) один треугольник и в CSS сделать `background-repeat-x`, чтобы он повторялся по оси абсцисс. Идей - сколько захотите. Все зависит от того, сколько у вас опыта, терпения и времени. Ну и насколько чисто вы хотите выполнить работу.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, я обновила, если можете, помогите, пож-ста.

Comment: @NNN Если честно, я не совсем понимаю, что не так: http://imgur.com/wvgbau1 Я готов вам помочь, но мне нужно видеть конкретный код (работающий, а не как на скриншоте), и не одну его часть, а в контексте. И да, на вашем месте я бы перевел обсуждение в чат :)

Comment: Что должен содержать код вкратце?

Comment: @NNN **Как минимум** еще и родителький блок. Желательно еще и соседние элементы. Чтобы представление могло сформироваться. Вообще, мне ли вас учить стоит тому, как код выкладывать? Что должно быть видно и какая часть его не работает - ту и выкладывайте (с теми, с которыми она взаимодействует).